# MySQL: M:N Table Linking Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-python

I'm getting ready to populate a couple of tables in a movie database I have created.  The `Movies` table has already been created.  It looks like this:

```
 movieid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 title VARCHAR(50)
 link  VARCHAR(100)
 release_date VARCHAR(10)
```

It should perhaps be noted that I'm using `MySQL-python` and `Scrapy` to populate this data in the `MySQL` database, but perhaps that doesn't matter.

I have created three additional tables which have not yet been populated: `Producers`, `Actors` and `Directors`.  Each of these looks like the other in that there exists `id`, `name` and `movie title`.  So `Actors` looks like:

```
 actorid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 actor   VARCHAR(40)
 title   VARCHAR(50)    <<<<------ This is the movie title from the Movies tables
```

Now, I would like to create a table called `Movie To Actor` which holds the `movieid` from the `Movie` table and the `actorid` from the `Actor` table and not have the `title` column existing in the `Actors` table.

I figure there are two ways to do this:

First Way:

Get all of the data into the `Actors` table with `title` acting as a `foreign key` and to THEN create the `Movie To Actor` table, adding the appropriate `ids` where `movies.title` is equal to `Actors.title` and to then drop the `title` column from `Actors`.

Second way:

Do this as I am populating the data.  First create the `Movie to Actor` table, set up key constraints and set this to auto update as the data is added to `Actors` table.  I would prefer this as it makes things significantly easier and I think is stylistically better.  Was hoping someone could instruct me on how I would go about doing this.  I think I can figure out how to extrapolate instructions in `MySQL` into `MySQL-python`, but would need help on how to do the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple points first off:

- Unless you're manually populating the actorid and movieid fields in the actors and movies tables you should have an auto_increment on those columns.
- If you're using movies.title to link to anything else, you should add a unique index to that column in the movies table.
- You should ultimately drop the title column from the actors table. Otherwise you'll either have multiple rows for the same actor name (redundant) or only one movie per actor (unrealistic).

For the first method you mentioned, you actually can *first* create the movie_actor table and *then* populate the existing data:

```
INSERT INTO movie_actor (movieid, actorid) SELECT movieid, actorid FROM movies INNER JOIN actors ON actors.title=movies.title;
```

For the second, you can use a trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER add_actor
AFTER INSERT ON actors
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @movieid = (SELECT movieid FROM movies WHERE title=NEW.title);
IF @movieid IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO movie_actor (movieid, actorid) VALUES (@movieid, NEW.actorid);
END IF;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

I'd suggest option 1 followed by having whatever form you're using to populate these tables to populate the movie_actor table independently (e.g. after adding an actor, you can set whatever movies he/she was in, merely adding a mapping to the movie_actor table). Then if you want to get a list of movies for an actor you can just

```
SELECT title FROM movie_actor
INNER JOIN movies ON movies.movieid=movie_actor.movieid
WHERE actorid=????
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read and post!  So, to reiterate and make sure I understand what you think I should do: I should first populate the `Actors` table, including the `title` column.  Then, I should populate the `movie_actor` table using the `INSERT SELECT` statement you wrote above.  Then I should remove the `title` column from the `Actors` table (reduce redundancy)?

Comment: Actually that query will `SELECT` from actors and movies at the same time for any actors already there who have the title column populated. If you do indeed redesign the input to drop the title column from actors and instead place the mappings directly in the movie_actor table, then the extra step of populating actors.title isn't needed. This would simply be for a one-time move.

Comment: Ok.  So, I can do that `INSERT SELECT` initially, drop the `title` from `Actors` and then setup the `TRIGGER`, in case, in the future`, I decide to add more actors?

Comment: The trigger I wrote would require the title column to exist in the actors table (`NEW.title`). What I was saying was the best design would be to do this: Add movies to the movies table. Add actors to the actors table. Add mappings identifying which actors are in which movies (movie_actor table). 3 separate actions. That would allow the most flexibility, since you won't be forcing yourself to add an actor to exactly one movie. For cleanliness, you might also want a trigger to delete from movie_actor if the corresponding movieid or actorid is deleted from their respective tables, however.